# Time Series in SAS getting contradiction?

Tags: time-series, sas, acf-pacf

The 2td graph shows auto-correlation function has significantly zero value after 10-ish but the table which checks nullity correlation says it has auto-correlation not-equal to 0 for lag=24 unlike to 2td graph says. Is it a SAS problem or Am I analyzing it in a wrong way?

[image]

Comment: The $p$-value in the table is for a "portmanteau" test which tests the nullity of all aucorrelations for the lags running from 1 to $m$. The second graph gives an interval for the autocorelation of each lag.

Comment: This series shows a strong trend.  That will be confounded with autocorrelation.  You have to choose how to model that trend--but doing it directly with some kind of AR model is not the right way.  Either incorporate covariates or difference it.  Consulting a practical textbook on time series analysis would be helpful.

Comment: These are two different hypotesis testing, I thought the second graph would've been based on the hypotesis testing used to make the table. Thank you all.